# PowerShell in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, powershell

In SQL Management Studio there is an option to start PowerShell via right-click on a database (for example).

However, I cannot run queries from that PowerShell session because, it claims, the login fails for my (domain) account.

I am logged in with the same account in Management Studio and started PowerShell from the Management Studio. How can I use the PowerShell session to do anything in SQL Server?

Command I tried was

```
invoke-sqlcmd "use sometable"
```

PowerShell then announced that it is using the "provider context" and deduces the SQL server name correctly. But then the query fails because "login failed for user 'mydomain\myaccount'".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you logged in to that specific instance of sqlserver with Windows authentication?

Comment: Yes. I started PowerShell from within SQL Management Studio by right-clicking on a database I could see/select from/update. In fact the error message specifically mentions my account which I am using.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a database named "sometable"?  The [USE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx) statement defines database context.

Try this:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd "select top 1 name from sys.tables"
```

Comment: The problem is the "login failed" message, not the contents of the command. I have a database called "sometable". But that's not the point. If I tried your example, I still wouldn't be logged in. Queries only work when the user is logged in.